# Layer on which ball belongs in tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, triangles

What is the most computationally efficient way to find the layer on which a ball (i) belongs when arranged in a tetrahedron or 3 dimensional triangle with a triangular base. The ball on the top layer is numbered one. The balls on the second layer are numbered 2 - 4. The fifth layer 4-10 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers corresponding to complete tetrahedra are called (unsurprisingly) tetrahedral numbers, the $n$th tetrahedral number being given by

$$
T_n = \binom{n+2}{3}
$$

If you have $m$ balls, therefore, you could do a quick-and-dirty estimate of the number of layers required to get to the $m$th ball by computing

$$
L_{est}(m) = \lfloor \sqrt[3]{6m} \rfloor
$$

In most cases, I think this will work.  For instance, anywhere between $21$ and $35$ balls require five layers, and sure enough, the floor of the cube root of any number between $126$ and $210$ is indeed $5$.

The answer will occasionally be higher.  For instance, $57$ balls require a seventh layer, but the floor of the cube root of $342$ is $6$.  This seems like a reasonably fast way to get close, though.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer; however, I am looking for a reliable way to calculate the layer. I tried adding a little bit to 6 but I cannot find a number in between 6 and 7 that can capture both 166 in the 9th layer and 680 in the 15th layer.

Comment: If you're just looking for efficiency, do you need a *single* formula that will give the *exact* answer for any input?  The answer should always be either the number yielded by the formula, or one higher.  (Most often it will be the number yielded by the formula.)

Answer (score 1):

**Background:**  The number of balls on layer $n$ is the $n$th [triangle number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)
$$
t_n = 1 + 2 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \binom{n+1}{2},
$$
and the total number of balls up to and including the $n$th layer is the $n$th [tetrahedral number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number)
$$
T_n = t_1 + t_2 + \cdots + t_n = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6} = \binom{n+2}{3}.
$$

**You question:**  given positive integer $i$, find the unique positive integer $n$ such that
$$
T_{n-1} < i \le T_n.
$$
From the inequalities
$$
\frac{(n-1)^3}{6} < T_{n-1} 
\quad\text{and}\quad 
T_n < \frac{(n+1)^3}{6}
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
(n-1)^3 < 6i &< (n+1)^3 \\
n-1 < \sqrt[3]{6i} &< n+1,
\end{align}
$$
which by rounding will get you $n$ within one.  Then just check $T_n$.

---

**Example:**  Say $i = 1\,000\,000$.  Then, $\sqrt[3]{6i} = 100\sqrt[3]{6} \approx 181$.  (I rounded down.)  Now,
$$
T_{181} = 1\,004\,731
$$
and
$$
T_{180} = 988\,260,
$$
so the millionth ball is on the $181$st layer.